# regex for matching url pattern not working

Tags: php, regex

I am having hard time creating a regular expression that should match all urls built on a particular pattern such as `http://subdomain.example.com/reply/aoo/spo/4429163785`

here is the regex I so far have written.

```
"/(^https?)(\:\/\/)([a-z]+)(\.craigslist\.org/reply)\/([a-z]{3}\/spo)\/([0-9]{10}$)/"
```

please help me improve my regex.

Comment: Enable error_reporting. There's an unescaped delimiter still.

Answer (score 1):

Change the delimiter to something else so you don’t need to escape it every now and then. Also, don’t capture those parts of the string where no variations are allowed (e.g. `.craigslist.org/reply/`):

```
"~^(https?)://([a-z]+)\\.craigslist\\.org/reply/([a-z]{3})/spo/([0-9]{10})$~"
```

Explanation:
`~` The opening delimiter
`^` Match the beginning of the string
`(https?)` Match either `http` or `https` – capture it
`://` Match a colon followed by two forward slashes
`([a-z]+)` Match one or more lowercase characters – capture it
`\\.` Match a period
`craigslist` Match the characters exactly as given
`\\.` Match a period
`org/reply/` Match the characters exactly as given
`([a-z]{3})` Match three lowercase characters – capture it
`/spo/` Match the characters exactly as given
`([0-9]{10})` Match ten numerical characters – capture it
`$` Match the ending of the string
`~` The closing delimiter

Comment: You’re welcome. Could you give me a list of URLs that you’d like to match with the regular expression?

Comment: I prefer using `[.]` for matching a literal `.` since it still leaes the regex more readable :)

Answer (score 1):

```
"/(^https?)(\:\/\/)([a-z]+)(\.craigslist\.org\/reply)\/([a-z]{3}\/spo)\/([0-9]{10}$)/"
```

You forgot to escape the `/` in after the .org part right before reply.